# How to use Kraken OCR in your python script?

Tags: ocr

There is this OCR library called "Kraken". I would like to build a script in Python that uses this library, but when I see documentation, it doesn't tell me anything about using it in the way "from kraken import ...". How to use that library in that way? I want to build a script for reading the text with Kraken, but I cannot find anything in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

[Kraken](http://kraken.re/) is a turn-key OCR system forked from [ocropus](https://github.com/ocropus).
It requires some external libraries to run.

**Installation**

- Using pip:

```
$ pip3 install kraken
```

- If you are running [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/)/miniconda, use:

```
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mittagessen/kraken/master/environment.yml
$ conda env create -f environment.yml
```

[Sample Code (Google Colab)](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1vjk-In0g9OKSRQJzqIG_F_Yq-xA8JPMp)

For more details see [the official documentation page](http://kraken.re/advanced.html).

Comment: From that link I cannot see usage in the form: "from kraken import some_class". The only way is written in the form of console way

Comment: ```from kraken import pageseg```
...
```help(pageseg)```